# The keyword const and the linker file

Tags: c

If I declare in a header file, for example, `extern unsigned long * Ptr;`
and the value of this pointer Ptr in the linker file.
Will this adrress be 'constant'? Can I change its value ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it in a short 20 line test program?

Comment: What do you mean by "this pointer"? The address of `Ptr`, like the address of any declared object, does not change. The address *contained* in `Ptr` can be changed to anything you like by assigning a value to it. (Your title mentions the `const` keyword, but you don't actually ask about it.)

Comment: Yes it's true; I have not used the “const” keyword. I'd say that if we just wrote `extern unsigned long * Ptr;` and in the linker file (not in the source files) we Add `Ptr=0x0012FFEE`.
This means that the address 0x0012FFEE and its value are constant (like if I wrote `extern const unsigned long * Ptr`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extern unsigned long *Ptr;
```

You can write to both `Ptr` (point to a new object) and `*Ptr` (update the thing being pointed to).

```
extern const unsigned long *Ptr;
extern unsigned long const *Ptr;
```

You can write to `Ptr` (point to a new object), but you cannot write to `*Ptr`.

```
extern unsigned long * const Ptr;
```

You can write to `*Ptr` (update the thing being pointed to), but you cannot write to `Ptr`.

```
extern const unsigned long * const Ptr;
extern unsigned long const * const Ptr;
```

You cannot write to either `Ptr` or `*Ptr`.

In all cases, the value of `&Ptr` does not change.

Naturally, this assumes a matching *defining* declaration for `Ptr`.